# How to Create Two level enum

Tags: c#, .net, oop, enums

Sorry if the question's title is confusing,but i don't know how to ask it.
what is really want is to have read-only data that will never change.

currently i have two enums `MeterType` and `SubMeterType`

```
public enum MeterType
{
  Water = 1001,
  Electricity = 1004,
  Gas = 1007
}
```

and

```
public enum SubMeterType
{
  DrinkingWater = 1002,
  UsageWater = 1003,
  SubsidiseGas = 1008,
  NonSusbsidisedGas = 1009
}
```

Now i would like to use these as follows

To get the MeterType

```
string meterType = MeterType.Water.ToString("d");
```

and to get the SubMeterType, is it possible to have something like

```
string subMeterType = MeterType.Water.DrinkingWater("d");
```

Shall go for another approach using classes with readonly properties ?
or modify these enums to suit my requirement.

Comment: Go for another approach, possibly a dictionary, otherwise you'll end up with SubsidiseGas Water.

Comment: Maybe you want to use java's approach and use classes with constant properties instead of enums

Comment: @Sayse can you please guide me how can i use dictionary for this scenario.

Comment: I don't really have time right now to give a full example but you coul d have a <MeterType, SubGasMeterType> or something, haven't fully thought of how to pad this out to be honest which is why there is a "possibly" prefix

Comment: @Sayse i will try to create a dictionary as you suggested.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of using enums you might use constant integers in nested classes:

```
public static class MeterType
{
    public const int Water = 1001;
    public const int Electricity = 1004;
    public const int Gas = 1007;

    public static class Waters
    {
        public const int DrinkingWater = 1002;
        public const int UsageWater = 1003;
    }

    public static class Gases
    {
        public const int SubsidiseGas = 1008;
        public const int NonSusbsidisedGas = 1009;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes this suits my requirement, the answer you posted before editing was having property and nested class name same `public const int Water = 1001;` and `public class Water`. is there any thing wrong using same name because i can use it like `MeterType.Water` and also `MeterType.Water.DrinkingWater`

Comment: @Mourya You can't have both `MeterType.Water` and `MeterType.Water.DrinkingWater` returning enum or int values. The closest thing I can think of would be making it so that you have `MeterType.Water.Value` instead of `MeterType.Water`, but I don't think that's of interest to you.

Comment: @S_F yes i would like to have `MeterType.Water`

Comment: @Mourya Copy and paste is a bad thing, if you copy the wrong code the first time. Therefore the edit.
Also this solution is a good way for deeper nested enuemrations.

Comment: @Herdo ya i know copy/paste is not good, but i was just check whether it would fit my requirement.

Comment: I made a suggestion on roslyn github project to implement this feature in next versions of c# (https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/13192), but I think that it will not gonna happen...

Answer (score 3):

Just use a nested enum:

```
public class MeterType
{
    public enum Water { }
}
```

But in this case you can't use `MeterType.Water` directly, this is not possible by default. Try use nested objects then or a secondary enum for the `MeterType`.

```
public enum MeterType { }
public enum MeterTypeWater { }
```

In this case you need a property with a different name for each of the enums. Best solution is to not use a nested class:

```
public class MeterType
{
    public static WaterType Water { get; }
}

public class WaterType
{
    public readonly SubWaterType DrinkingWater = SubWaterType.DrinkingWater;
}
```

Comment: it is not possible it is showing error of identifier expected

Comment: @Co.Aden Of course you need entries in the `Water` enum. That should be quite clear, right?

Comment: this gives error                                                      public enum saa
        { 
            public enum dd {ne = 1},
            ff = 2
        }

Comment: @Co.Aden Not nested enums, this is not possible, nested class & enum.

Comment: @FelixK. thanks for the answer , but how can get value for only Water like `MeterType.Water` ?

Comment: @Mourya Use the last approach or use multiple enums. :-/

Comment: @FelixK. i will try for some other possibilities or else i will go for multiple enums.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot nest `enum`s but you already know that. What you can do is to have `const` or `readonly` properties/fields which map to the various types you want. Then in each of the types, you define fields/properties for the subtypes.

```
public static class MeterTypes
{
    public static readonly Electricity electricity;
    public static readonly Gas gas;
    public static readonly Water water;

    static MeterTypes()
    {
        // initialize the meter types to their default
        MeterTypes.Water = Water.GenericWater;
        MeterTypes.Gas = Gas.GenericGas;
        MeterTypes.Electricity = Electricity.GenericElectricity;
    }

    private MeterTypes()
    {
        // private initialization prevents others from creating the class            
    }

    public class Electricity
    {
        public enum Type
        {
            Generic = 1007,
            SubsidisedElectricity = 1008,
            NonSubsidisedElectricity = 1009
        }

        public static readonly Electricity GenericElectricity;
        public static readonly Electricity SubsidisedElectricity;
        public static readonly Electricity NonSubsidisedElectricity;
        private Type ElectricityType;

        static Electricity()
        {
            SubsidisedElectricity = new Electricity(Type.SubsidisedElectricity);
            NonSubsidisedElectricity = new Electricity(Type.NonSubsidisedElectricity);
            GenericElectricity = new Electricity(Type.Generic);
        }

        // private constructor prevents creation from outside the class
        private Electricity(Type ElectricityType)
        {
            this.ElectricityType = ElectricityType;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return ElectricityType.ToString();
        }

        public string ToString(string format)
        {
            return ElectricityType.ToString(format);
        }
    }

    public class Gas
    {
        public enum Type
        {
            Generic = 1007,
            SubsidisedGas = 1008,
            NonSubsidisedGas = 1009
        }

        public static readonly Gas GenericGas;
        public static readonly Gas SubsidisedGas;
        public static readonly Gas NonSubsidisedGas;
        private Type gasType;

        static Gas()
        {
            SubsidisedGas = new Gas(Type.SubsidisedGas);
            NonSubsidisedGas = new Gas(Type.NonSubsidisedGas);
            GenericGas = new Gas(Type.Generic);
        }

        // private constructor prevents creation from outside the class
        private Gas(Type gasType)
        {
            this.gasType = gasType;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return gasType.ToString();
        }

        public string ToString(string format)
        {
            return gasType.ToString(format);
        }
    }

    public class Water
    {
        public enum Type
        {
            Generic = 1001,
            DrinkingWater = 1002,
            UsageWater = 1003
        }

        public static readonly Water GenericWater;
        public static readonly Water DrinkingWater;
        public static readonly Water UsageWater;
        private Type waterType;

        static Water()
        {
            DrinkingWater = new Water(Type.DrinkingWater);
            UsageWater = new Water(Type.UsageWater);
            GenericWater = new Water(Type.Generic);
        }

        // private constructor prevents creation from outside the class
        private Water(Type waterType)
        {
            this.waterType = waterType;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return waterType.ToString();
        }

        public string ToString(string format)
        {
            return waterType.ToString(format);
        }
    }
}
```

This can be used as such

```
var w = MeterTypes.water; // will give generic water
var uw = MeterTypes.Water.UsageWater // will give usage water
```

and you get the added use of the `Enum.ToString()` methods too.

You'll have to note that this implementation relies on C#'s case sensitivity. This makes `MeterTypes.electricity` and `MeterTypes.Electricity` refer to a field and a class respectively. This code will is very likely to fail if it ever gets used in a language that is not case sensitive (e.g. VB.NET). You could circumvent this by using a different name for the static fields in the `MeterTypes` class (e.g. `_Electricity` instead of `electricity`).